# gem install compass-rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

gem install compass-rails

[/home/shanks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/compass-rails-1.0.3.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
[/home/shanks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/compass-rails-1.0.3.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove these files, using

```
rm /home/shanks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/compass-rails-1.0.3.gemspec
rm /home/shanks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/compass-rails-1.0.3.gemspec
```

And then try using your command. This worked when I had such issue.